# Getting Values from a table column and inserting to another table

Tags: sql

Currently I have a table **extended_values** that stores 3 custom value for a user in the following way.

```
+------+-------+---------+
| Name | Value | UserKey |
+------+-------+---------+
| cs1  | tgb   |     100 |
| cs2  | hhy   |     100 |
| cs3  | ttr   |     100 |
| cs1  | hht   |     104 |
| cs2  | iyu   |     104 |
| cs3  | uyt   |     104 |
| cs1  | tjg   |     106 |
| cs2  | yyt   |     106 |
| cs3  | try   |     106 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

I have another table **user_custom_property** with four columns, userkey, cs1, cs2 and cs3 and i need to store the values in the following format

```
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
| userkey | cs1 | cs2 | cs3 |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
|     100 | tgb | hhy | ttr |
|     104 | hht | iyu | uyt |
|     106 | tjg | yyt | try |
+---------+-----+-----+-----+
```

There are almost 75000 user with 3 custom value, so the query should be optimized not to consume more resources in terms of memory.

So technically i need to query the extended_values table get the value corresponding to cs1,cs2 and cs3 for a userkey and store the values in the following way inside user_custom_property.

What would be an efficent way to do this.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Given a user you want to find `cs1`, `cs2` and `cs3` and then do what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `GROUP BY` and `CASE` will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE extended_values (
  name VARCHAR(20),
  value VARCHAR(20),
  userkey INT
);

INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs1', 'tgb', 100);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs2', 'hhy', 100);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs3', 'ttr', 100);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs1', 'hht', 104);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs2', 'iyu', 104);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs3', 'uyt', 104);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs1', 'tjg', 106);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs2', 'yyt', 106);
INSERT INTO extended_values VALUES ('cs3', 'try', 106);

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE user_custom_property (
  userkey INT,
  cs1 VARCHAR(20),
  cs2 VARCHAR(20),
  cs3 VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO user_custom_property
  SELECT
      userkey,
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'cs1' THEN value END),
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'cs2' THEN value END),
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'cs3' THEN value END)
    FROM extended_values
  GROUP BY userkey;

SELECT * FROM user_custom_property;
```

Output:

```
   USERKEY CS1                  CS2                  CS3                
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
       100 tgb                  hhy                  ttr                  
       104 hht                  iyu                  uyt                  
       106 tjg                  yyt                  try
```

Check at SQLFiddle:

- [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a1948/1)
- [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a194/1)
- [PostreSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2a194/1)
- [SQLServer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a194/1)

**Edit**

Regarding the question in the comment - you just have to change the values in the `CASE`:

```
INSERT INTO user_custom_property
  SELECT
      userkey,
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'ea1' THEN value END),
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'ea2' THEN value END),
      MIN(CASE WHEN name = 'ea3' THEN value END)
    FROM extended_values
  GROUP BY userkey;
```

Comment: Hi Przemyslaw, I have 75000 userkey and running this script for 75000 isn't a feasible option. Is there a way i can pass all the userkey in a go. I sthere a way i can store all the userkey in a  variable

Comment: @navman Is this a one-time script? Have you tried running this query?

Comment: @navman I have just run a test on a table with 75000 different userkeys and it took 0,1 of a second. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw, what if name in extended_values table is ea1, ea2, ea3 and name in user_custom_property is cs1, cs2 and cs3. The value corresponding to ea1 should be stored under cs1, similarly value coresponding to ea2 should be stored under cs2 and there on.....so how do i modify your above query then.

Comment: @navman All you need to do is change the values in the `CASE` expressions - I've edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks a ton Przemslaw Kruglej